# Why won't my character move?

Tags: java, eclipse, keylistener

I have my code.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 37){
        personx -=2;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 38){
        persony -=2;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 39){
        personx +=2;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 40){
        persony +=2;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep((long) 0.04);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code will not move the character.
I checked if it was being called and I wrote:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

But it did not print Test.

Comment: Where's the code that adds the listener?

Comment: How is the listener attached?

Comment: `Thread.sleep((long) 0.04);` is the same as `Thread.sleep(0);` which is the same as `// no code at all`

Comment: Is this a Swing application? And what does Java-EE (enterprise edition) have to do with anything in your question? Or Eclipse for that matter? Your question is short on a lot of necessary details. Consider telling these to us.

Comment: I'm sorry I was just adding that encase i was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggests that you're working on either a Swing or an AWT GUI. Either way for KeyListeners to work you need to:

- First add the KeyListener to a component that's on the visible GUI
- Make sure that that component is *Focusable*
- And that the listened to component has the GUI's focus.

If this were a Swing GUI, I'd recommend that you not in fact use a KeyListener but rather use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) since these are more flexible than KeyListeners and allow you to re-use AbstractActions in multiple parts of your program.